# Should I compile a library from source?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I'm working on an application that will run on a custom-built, debian-based linux system. We have a toolchain so that we can cross-compile the application for the target system, that way we don't have to depend on the host OS (as opposed to target OS) on which we're doing the compilation.

I'm not sure, however if we should be cross-compiling the 3rd party libraries from source or whether we should just use the pre-canned libraries and header files. For example, libSDL1.2 seems to be distro-agnostic based on this page (http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php) so it would seem that we don't need to compile it from source.. but some other libraries have different flavors for BSD, Ubuntu, Redhat, etc. which makes me think that we need to compile those with our toolchain.

When should I compile a library from source? What things are there to consider?

Comment: What is your host OS? I for one am used to cross-compiling, but both on Debian hosts / for Debian targets so I can easily take advantage of multiarch packages or at the very worst use `xapt` to draw in linkable libraries on the host. Then I just install the same packages on the target and all runs smoothly. When cross-compiling for a Debian target, using a Debian host (whatever the architecture) really makes your life easier because you never have to manually compile libs that are available in the repos (and Debian repos are *huge*!).

Comment: Also note that many Debian packages (like other distros) have distro-specific patches to allow the software to play nice with the distro as a whole. So compiling from upstream source might not be such a good idea, you'll probably want to compile from Debian sources instead. Which in turn often involves Debian-specific tools. Which in turn requires a Debian host. And if you're on a Debian host, multiarch/xapt makes recompilation pointless in the first place. I guess you get my point by now. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good thing to compile/build a 3rd-party library from source. Although some libraries like `OpenCV` or `libSDL` you mentioned can be directly used without compiling, you can still benefit a lot by re-build them according to your preferred options instead of using their default options. For example, by re-build `OpenCV`, you can add `CUDA` feature that is suitable for your PC to speed it up.

To compile/build a 3rd-party, you can use `cmake`. For most 3rd-party libraries, they contain a file called `CMakeLists.txt` for you to do that.